# Is there a way to edit my HTP Trophy (WP7.5) registry that doesn't require unlocking my device?

Tags: 7.5

I want to edit my phone's registry so that I can attempt to fix an issue with my browser tabs, but *every single solution* I come across requires me to dev unlock my phone and I am not 1) faking a DreamSpark account or 2) paying Microsoft $99 a year for a subscription.  I feel I am about to go on a serious rage rant just talking about that, so I am going to stop before I get myself into trouble here.

I need a *free* method to edit my WP7.5 registry that doesn't require me to unlock my phone.

Comment: Not that it helps, but the registration fee is now $19 USD.

Comment: @row1 Are you certain that's still valid?  "This offer is valid beginning 6/26/2013 12:00 AM PST and ending 8/27/2013 12:00 AM PST" http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2013/06/26/microsoft-slashes-windows-phone-developer-annual-registration-fee-from-99-to-19-for-the-next-60-days/.  Granted, I only researched it for a minute.  Can you provide a link that states this is the new annual fee, that's it's not just an introductory fee that will just go back up to $99 the following year?

Comment: They decided to make it permanent http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join . I don't see anything about it going back to $99, and if it does then you can just cancel it.

Comment: It also doesn't auto-renew, nor do unlocked devices relock automatically

Comment: What do you need to change in the registry anyway? There might be a better way of doing it through a different method

Comment: @RowlandShaw See this question: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/i-cant-open-new-ie-tabs-on-my-wp7-5.  I read that you can potentially fix that tab issue by editing the registry and setting the number of open tabs to 0.  Apparently, it's possible that some bug has locked the number of currently opened tabs to 6.  This causes IE to think it's maxed out in open tabs which keeps any additional tabs from being open even though there are currently none.

Answer (score 1):

There is no free way of doing what you want, as far as I know. If you really need registry access, pay the $19 USD per year. And maybe try your hand at the [App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/) to easily create a specific app you might want as well: for that $19 you can publish that app worldwide.